# Pass select list selected value in model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have following model class

```
class Emp
{
    int id { get; set; }
    string name { get; set; }
    Role role { get; set; }
}
class Role
{
    int id { get; set; }
    string rolename { get; set; }
}
```

and below is my form to perform update entity
**.aspx**

```
@using(@Html.BeginForm("edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post)){

            <label>name: </label>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)<br />
            <label>role: </label>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Role, (SelectList)ViewBag.roles)

            @Html.Hidden("empid", Model.EmpId)

            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        }
```

`C#` Action Method

```
public ActionResult edit(Emp emp)
{
      if (ModelState.IsValid) // <-- always returning false
      {
          // Model.Role getting null, why ?
      }
}
```

To populate dropdown the `selectList`

```
ViewBag.roles = new SelectList(dbContext.Roles, "roleid", "rolename", SelectedRole);
```

now in edit method `emp` model contains `empid` and `name`, but `role` getting `null`, any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the reason is that, model binder cannot bind complex types contained in the model. You can possibly get this to work by having a RoleId field in the Emp model and then binding the drop down to that RoleId.

Or you can go for editor templates to achieve intended functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't anything to tell it how to create a Role object from the value of the selected role on the post back.  Also, when creating the view, it also has no idea which property of the Role object to use to select an item in the drop down.

So in short you should bind the drop down to a property of type string not a user defined type.

Answer (score 0):

I thinck it should be

```
ViewBag.roles = new SelectList(dbContext.Roles, "id", "rolename", SelectedRole);
```

"id" instead of "roleid"